# Azure powershell changes to check for file in Azure Data lake storage Gen 1 and trigger a BAT script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-lake

I need to run a BAT file once the file is available in Azure Data lake Storage - Gen 1. I have the PowerShell script which does the folder check from my C:\Temp, but I need this to be changed to Azure Data lake storage path location.

Instead of C:\Temp I use `AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem`, but facing errors in this.

Below is the PS Script:

```
 Param (
    #[string]$Path = "C:\Temp"
    [string]$Path = "Test-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "aruntesting1" -Path "/MyFiles/test.csv" "
    )

### Look for any files from the path mentioned above
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = $Path
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { 
                $A = Start-Process -FilePath C:\Users\arsivana\Desktop\Arun\Project\xyz\test.bat -Wait -passthru;$a.ExitCode
              } 


### Events to be watched 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 2}
```

Comment: As far as I know, if you run the PowerShell script on-premise, you need to download the bat file at first then you can run the bat file. Regarding how to download file, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-powershell#rename-download-and-delete-data-from-your-data-lake-storage-gen1-account

Comment: Jim - I have this powershell script in my desktop folder and it will run for every 10 minutes using Windows scheduler..but the test.bat file should get triggered only when there is a file available in Azure Data lake storage..so in this case if test.csv file is available then test.bat should get triggered..

Comment: According to my understanding, you want to check if one file exists in Azure data lake store. And the bat file is on-premises. Is that right?

Comment: Besides, could you please provide me the error message?

Comment: yes Jim thats right

Comment: Error message - At line:3 char:64
+ ... string]$Path = " Test-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "aruntest ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing ')' in function parameter list.
At line:4 char:2
+     )
+     ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInFunctionParameterList

Comment: As far as I know, the command ```Test-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem``` is used to check if the account has the file. If it has, it will return ```true```. Otherwise, it will return ```false```. For more details, please refer to hhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/test-azurermdatalakestoreitem?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: Yes Jim..but what changes do i need to do for checking the data from Azure data lake storage Gen 1 instead of checking C:\ folder

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: In the below code  i have commented the path to check whether some file has been created in C:\Temp. Instead i have to check the Azure Data lake storage path /Myfiles/test.csv exists or not..in case of C:\Temp if any file gets created then the bat script file gets executed..                                                                                        
   Param (
    #[string]$Path = "C:\Temp"
    [string]$Path = "Test-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "aruntesting1" -Path "/MyFiles/test.csv" "
    )

Comment: According to research, the command ```Test-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem``` is used to check if a file exists in the account. If file exists, it returns ```true```. Otherwise, it returns ```false```. So I think you can use the script to trigger ```$result = Test-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Account $account -Path $path -PathType File
if($result){ Start-Process }```.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: No Thanks Jim for your support

Comment: If you have no other concerns, could you please accept my suggestions? It may help more people.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, the command `Test-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem` is used to check if a file exists in the account. If file exists, it returns true. Otherwise, it returns false. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/test-azurermdatalakestoreitem?view=azurermps-6.13.0). So I think you can use the script to trigger

```
$result = Test-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Account $account -Path $path -PathType File
 if($result){ Start-Process }
```

Comment: @arun If it is ok for you, please accept the answer. It may assist persons who have similar issue.